# JBoss & warbler: no such file to load

Tags: jboss, jruby, warbler

guys.

I'm using Rails 3.2.13, jruby-1.7.12, JBoss EAP 6.2 and warbler 1.4.3.dev(have tried 1.4.1 and 1.4.2 - it doesn't matter). And I got such error while entering first page of my application:

> 19:32:18,822 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) ERROR: initialization failed: org.jruby.rack.RackInitializationException: no such file to load -- /home/alex/Projects/install_test/eap-6.2/jboss-eap-6.2/standalone/tmp/vfs/temp/temp37c8c04246e7d946/content-69d213af89011d97/home/alex/Projects/install_test/eap-6.2/jboss-eap-6.2/standalone/tmp/vfs/temp/temp37c8c04246e7d946/content-95fa3e2c22b1402c/config/environment.rb

I got this error only when there are two different deployments in my JBoss:
[image: Available Deployments]
Where ap_ROOT.war is my rails application and rp_app.war is my java application. In case when there is only rails application there are no errors.

As I found

> /home/alex/Projects/install_test/eap-6.2/jboss-eap-6.2/standalone/tmp/vfs/temp/temp37c8c04246e7d946/content-69d213af89011d97

is the path to the rp_app.war(java application) deployment folder and

> /home/alex/Projects/install_test/eap-6.2/jboss-eap-6.2/standalone/tmp/vfs/temp/temp37c8c04246e7d946/content-95fa3e2c22b1402c

is the path to the app_ROOT.war(rails application) deployment folder.

Someway it get messed up and JBoss can't find 'config/environment.rb'.

Thanks,
Alex.

Comment: it would likely be more useful to see the full (Java) stack-trace (and/or Ruby backtrace)